# Configure external clock for atmega 1281 on proteus

Tags: c, avr, atmega

Creating a stopwatch and want to measure the time more accurately, no matter what frequency is used(8MHz. 4MHz,2MHz,1MHz) in the internal oscillator, there are always errors with the counting time depending on the frequency (10-20 seconds delay)
 already connected the 8MHz crystal, 2, 20pF capacitors to XTAL1, and XTAL2 ports on proteus board but have no idea about how to configure the fuses thing in avr coding in C

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Proteus Board? If you are referring to Proteus Simulation, then you don't have to program the fuse bits in the micro-controller under the simulation environment. But you can choose the Clock type (External/Internal) and provide the frequency value by right clicking on the microcontroller and then click on properties. If you want to set the fuse bits in actual hardware/PCB mounted MCU, let me know the IDE you are using.